# IEnumerator moving back to record

Tags: c#, .net

I have requirement in which I have to back and fort with record. So I am using IEnumerator to that. But I can move forward by movenext but there no way to move back

Comment: Do you want to implement your *own* container that will provide forward and backward enumeration capability, or are you using another standard container and want to "move back"?

Comment: I am using standard container and want to move back

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one way you could wrap an `IEnumerator<T>`, by capturing its contents in a `List<T>` as it moves along:

```
public interface ITwoWayEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    bool MovePrevious();
}

public class TwoWayEnumerator<T> : ITwoWayEnumerator<T>
{
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private List<T> _buffer;
    private int _index;

    public TwoWayEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        if (enumerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");

        _enumerator = enumerator;
        _buffer = new List<T>();
        _index = -1;
    }

    public bool MovePrevious()
    {
        if (_index <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        --_index;
        return true;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_index < _buffer.Count - 1)
        {
            ++_index;
            return true;
        }

        if (_enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            _buffer.Add(_enumerator.Current);
            ++_index;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_index < 0 || _index >= _buffer.Count)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return _buffer[_index];
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _enumerator.Reset();
        _buffer.Clear();
        _index = -1;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

Then I would expose this kind of enumerator using an extension method:

```
public static class TwoWayEnumeratorHelper
{
    public static ITwoWayEnumerator<T> GetTwoWayEnumerator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullExceptions("source");

        return new TwoWayEnumerator<T>(source.GetEnumerator());
    }
}
```

Note that this is definitely overkill if the collection you're dealing with is already an indexed collection such as a `T[]` or a `List<T>`. It makes more sense for scenarios such as when you're enumerating over a sequence that isn't already in a conveniently indexed form and you want to be able to go backwards as well as forwards.

Answer (score 4):

The `IEnumerator` (and `IEnumerator<T>`) interfaces only implement a forward only enumerator.  You'll need to make your own class or interface if you want to allow bi-directional iteration through your collection.

Comment: Is there any other inteface which I can implement for fullfil this requirement ?

Comment: @Huzaifa: There isn't anything built-into the framework.  You could easily just take your collection, treat it as a list, and maintain a current index, but there's nothing built-in to do this...

Comment: It's probably easiest to just implement `IList<T>` and keep track of the index. Implementing this interface is a bit of a pain, so I have in my personal library a [ListBase](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54571#724163) class (which uses the [ListHelper](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54571#724166) class).

Comment: @Steven: He's, unfortunately, "using a standard container" already - so I don't think he can implement his own class.  He probably needs to convert it to a list and work with it, or write a custom iterator class for working with standard containers...

Answer (score 2):

You can't go backwards with IEnumerator. Either suck the entire set into a List or cache the current element on each pass through the loop, so it's available to the next pass.