# c# struct with reference to struct

Tags: c#, struct, ref

I got a structure called `TWord`defined like that:

```
struct TWord{
    public string Text
    /*Some more stuff*/

    public TWord(string fText){this.Text = fText;}
}
```

A word is a word in a text. Now, I'd like to insert two references of TWord in the struct TWord. It should look like this:

```
struct TWord{
    public string Text
    public TWord PreviousWord;
    public TWord NextWord;

    public TWord(string fText, ref TWord fPreviousWord = null, ref TWord fNextWord = null){ 
        this.Text = fText; 
        this.PreviousWord = fPreviousWord;
        this.NextWord = fNextWord;
    }
}
```

In C++, this is no problem, but does not work in C#. I get the error `Struct member TWord.PreviousWord` of type `TWord`causes a cycle in the struct layout.

How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Why aren't you using a class?

Comment: Would be possible, because a class is a reference. But I'd would like to learn new stuff.

Comment: So what exactly are you learning here? That using circular references with struct is not going to work?

Comment: A C# struct is a ValueType. So that's not quite the same as in C++.

Comment: I guess lesson learned.

Comment: In c# structures do not have methods.  When interface to c++ you want to use structure not classes but include method outside the structure.

Comment: But can't a struct in C# contain a ref type variable? Or is that only working in unsafe mode?

Comment: Since structs in C# are value types and not reference types the compiles wants to optimize the memory layout of `TWord` through embedding another `TWord` which leads to a cyclic type reference which can't be solved. Just use `class` or `nullable` filed of your strucutre type like `TWord?`

Comment: Ok guys, we're leafing the circle. If the answer is, that a struct in C# cannot contain a reference to the same type, than thank you, I learned that and then I've to use a class. But if it is possible (without unsafe coding), I'd like to know how it works.

Comment: It doesn't work :)

Comment: In C++, a `struct` is nearly exactly the same as a `class`. The only difference is that in a struct, members are public by default. In a class, the default is private. In C#, classes and structs are fundamentally different. C# structs are _value types_ (compared with reference types like classes). In C++, the difference between value and reference is determined by syntax (references are either pointers or `&` references). In C++, your NextWord and PreviousWord members would be pointers (/references), not values

Comment: Hey Flydog - but would it be possible to cast a ref TWord to an System.IntPtr? So, I could define System.IntPtr PreviousWord and System.IntPtr NextWord.

Comment: @jdweng: In C#, structs most definitely can have methods. Consider `double.Parse` or any of the other methods on the basic value types

Comment: Ok, the casting does not work - neighter explicit nor implicit.

Comment: a little correction of my previous comment: a nullable field is also not going to work because the type `System.Nullable<T>` is also a struct and also leads to cyclic type reference when the compiler optimizes the layout. It has to be a class or you need your own Wrapper which needs to be a class

Comment: @jan021981: oh, don't do that. Use the system the way it's designed. Use it correctly and it _Just Works_. By the way, if you look at a standard implementation of a doubly linked list, your final try of TWord looks a lot like the `Node<T>` that is used to represent the reference to the things being collected. Find a doubly linked list, and make your implementation be a `DblLinkedList<string>`

Answer (score -1):

Structs in general are for smaller object - some say under 16bytes - for your application a struct is inappropriate only by the size in memory that it can take up. Struct are supposed to be simple and small data carriers. If you want to make bigger structures that also recursively call stuff or can contain bigger lists you should use `classes`. This all is discussed here [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

In your case I would even suggest you use a `List<strings>` or a `List<World>` you are refering to the next and previous item which is exactly what a List does. You can  move next, and using the [c5 collection libary](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) equivalent youre also allowed to move back. (Alternatively you can [buffer the List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3261309/6401643) to achieve the same effect).

Using existing and well optimized libaries will safe you some hassle and genrally make your code look clear and run faster, therefore I would advice you to do so wherever you can.

Comment: Also C# generally passes a reference, using the ref keyword you indicate that you want to write to the object passed, instead of creating a copy for changes. But since you only read data Roslyn will give you a reference instead of an object anyways.